# IF 404 add subdomain with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am getting 404s as I added a subdomain to my website.

New site layout = mysite.com/* to sub.mysite.com/*

When you get a 404 from the mysite.com/* I would like a subdomain added so sub.mysite.com/*

Making final url =  sub.mysite.com/*

How would I go about getting this to work with htaccess?

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you ask. Please take the time to revise your question and try to work out better what exactly it is you want to do.

Comment: Fixed. Take a look now! @arkascha

Comment: Ok, thanks, much better. However I am still puzzled: I can see only one single host name ("subdomain") in use here: `sub.mysite.com`. Since that would be a static setup no dynamic creation would be required. So the question is: how should those dynamic host names look like? What logic is there to be implemented?

Comment: There is dynamic content though. The * could be 1 of 5000+ possible routes  that are valid. I need an htaccess file for my old mysite.com root to point to the new sub.mysite.com route with the requested link. mysite.com/example.jpg would 404, and make it sub.mysite.com/example.jpg. The example.jpg could change to anything though. @arkascha

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand. So you do _not_ want "sub domains" to be added. You have a static second host name and want to redirect requests to the first host that would result in a status 404 to the second host, leaving the URL unchanged otherwise.

Comment: Em, there seems to be a confusion here: it might be the same host, but you probably want different host names. `mysite.com` is the only domain involved here. `mysite.com`, `www.mysite.com`, `blog.mysite.com` are all host names. They _might_ resolve to the same host or system or address, sure.

Comment: Oh okay. Well if it is a 404 on mysite.com/* I want to add blog.mysite.com/*. Where * is the requested url - make sense?

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense. Are you sure that you do not confuse "host name" with "host"/"system"?

Comment: The term "sub domain" does not really make much sense. There are only domains and host names. Host names are used to identify and differ between virtual hosts served by some http server.

Comment: Okay. How do I add a new host name (blog.mysite.com) when main hostname mysite.com/* 404s.

Comment: It _seems_ that you cannot directly use the apache features to implement what you ask... You'd need to implement a redirection handler (a script) that is used as an internal error document, which receives the original request and sends out a redirection header to the client. The error handling features the apache http server itself offers do not appear to be flexible enough to allow them to be changed with redirection rules. Sorry.

Comment: To serve requests to some other host name you add a virtual host to your apache configuration. See the documentation for that. It comes with great examples. But that is separate from the redirection issue you ask about.

Comment: Ah, I finally found a definite answer in the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html  See the remark for "Redirect Failing URLs To Other Webserver" in there. It describes _exactly_ what you are looking for...

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try.